# не получается получить данные из БД MySQl с помощью модуля peewee

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

```
from peewee import*

# включение бд
db = MySQLDatabase('namedb', user ='root', password ='*****',
host='localhost', port=3306)

class Base(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Line(Base):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(unique=True)
    name = CharField()
    subname = CharField()
    prinadleznost = CharField()
    god_prokladki = CharField()

def find_all_lines():
    return line.select()
lines = find_all_lines()
id = []
for line in lines:
    id.append({
        'наименование': line.name,
        'Номер': line.subname,
        'Сеть': line.prinadleznost
    })

print(id)


Выдает ошибку:models.py", line 23, in <module>
    lines = find_all_lines()
line 22, in find_all_lines
    return line.select()
NameError: name 'line' is not defined
```

Comment: Что такое "не получается"? Если выходит ошибка - приведите её текст в вопросе. Если поведение кода отличается от ожидаемого - напишите в вопросе, что вы ожидали, и что получили.

Comment: Выскакивает много ошибок. Если меняю запрос на вот этот for Line in line.select():
    print(Line.name). Появляется models.py", line 19, in <module>
    for Line in line.select():
NameError: name 'line' is not defined

Comment: Пишите всё это в вопросе. Если с другим кодом другие ошибки - пишите изменения кода ниже в вопросе, и ошибки которые при этом под кодом пишите. Никому не интересно читать все комментарии, вся информация должна быть прямо в тексте вопроса. За форматирование особо не беспокойтесь, если что-то не знаете как оформить, форматирование вам поправят если что.

Answer (score 0):

```
﻿from peewee import*

# включение бд
db = MySQLDatabase('namedb', user ='root', password ='****',
host='localhost', port=3306)

class Base(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Line(Base):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(unique=True)
    name = CharField()
    subname = CharField()
    prinadleznost = CharField()
    god_prokladki = CharField()

for line in Line.select():
    print(line.name,'|',line.subname,'|', line.prinadleznost, '|', line.god_prokladki)
```

Код работает